# Is there a way to link multiple Apple developer accounts with a single iTunes Connect account?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

My organization has two teams setup on developer.apple.com. One is used for development and the other is solely used for publishing to the app store. As far as I'm aware there's only an iTunes Connect account associated with the publishing team. There is a record setup in iTunes connect for the release version of our app. Normally this setup isn't an issue, but we need to use Game Center and it requires an iTunes connect record. But the release version and development version have different bundle IDs. So Game Center cannot currently be tested on the development version.

Is there a way to test Game Center in our development version without having to either create a new iTunes Connect account for it or without having to change the bundle ID for the development version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but one of your iTunesConnect accounts is useless and this answer assume you are an org on iTunesConnect not two different solo developer accounts.

You should never have two iTunesConnect accounts for one App.
Each iTunesConnect acc supports multiple appID's (think Facebook app + Facebook messenger).
each appID supports multiple provisioning profiles which each have share the entitlements of the App to use Game Center (or w/e other entitlements). Examples are Distribution, Ad Hoc, and Development.

To get what you are looking for, you want to use one iTunesConnectAccount, with one AppID (the one with the Game Center Entitlement), and then for that single AppID (one appID for every bundleID), create multiple profiles that you can use for release and Development.

To do this:

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list, after logging with a dev account associated with your org's iTunesConnect account.
2. Hit the + Icon to add a new profile.
3. Select the type of profile you want (in your case Development).
4. You will see a drop down where you can choose which appID(with associated bundleID).
5. Finish setup of profile.
6. In Xcode, navigate to Preferences -> Accounts, and download manual provisioning profiles.[image]
7. You should be able to put debug builds on physical device now that Development profile is imported for the same bundleID that you have Distribution enabled on and since Game Center entitlement is associated with that same AppID you shouldn't have any issues.

I'm assuming whoever created distribution profile to get a release version out never created equivalent development profile for the same app.

Here is high quality diagram illustrating the relationship of Accounts, Devs, Apps, Profiles, and Certs. (Credit MS Paint)

[image]

TLDR: Can't have one app for two accounts, you need to have one account w/ app and enable seperate profiles for distribution and development.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you're essentially saying that we need to stop using the development team and create a provisioning profile that's on the release team's account? Then we can add the development bundle ID to the iTunes Connect record?

Comment: Yes that's basically what I'm saying, no real reason release and development team have separate iTunesConnect accounts assuming it's the same app/company managing the teams. That is kind of what versioning is for. I.E. release can be  refining v3.4 while development can work off 3.5 and then release pushes 3.4 to iTunesConnect for testflight/release once it's done. Unless you're both working on separate repositories? But idk why you'd have two repo's for the same app.

Comment: You can think of it from apple's perspective. Why would two DIFFERENT "orgs" (how do they know you are same company), share same entitlements/code signing/but w/ different provisioning for the same app? They wouldn't give development access to google for an app released by facebook.